# Spring Boot startup fail after adding Axis 2 client dependencies

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, apache-axis, rampart

I am developing a demo application for consuming a Soap Web Service and I am using axis 2 as client. I decided to use Spring boot and merge my code into it. At first the simple Spring Boot was completely Ok and I could create a demo jsp page and a couple of rest webservices. After I added stub code jar files and also the Axis and Rampart dependencies into pom.xml it keeps getting error at startup.

Here is an snippet code for pom.xml the issue is easily replicable by just adding

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-metadata</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

into a simple spring boot pom.xml file that uses embedded tomcat and jasper.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
...
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <axis.version>1.7.1</axis.version>
        <rampart.version>1.7.1</rampart.version>
    </properties>
...

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>

        </dependency>

...
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-metadata</artifactId>
            <version>${axis.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I get the following error in console for mvn spring-boot:run

```
2017-10-27 15:20:29.433  INFO 26486 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
2017-10-27 15:20:29.513 ERROR 26486 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5117) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:182) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was a transitive dependency "`javax.servlet:servlet-api`" that comes with "`org.apache.axis2:axis2-metadata`".

I fixed that by excluding it from the axis2 and rampart dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-metadata</artifactId>
        <version>${axis.version}</version>  
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>       
    </dependency>
```